# Can I target a given Windows Terminal "session" when invoking `wt.exe`?

Tags: windows-10, windows-terminal

I replaced the entry [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org) creates in the context menu of directories to start the `bash.exe` inside Windows Terminal. This appears to work fine, except for one aspect.

The way I did this was by simply adding a "Git Bash" profile (I used `-l -i` as arguments to `bash.exe`, btw) and then starting this instead of `git-bash.exe` (not a typo, this one starts a terminal suitable for `bash.exe` and then Bash itself), i.e. something along the lines of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe -p "Git Bash" -d "%V"` in the registry key **but** with the respective variable *already expanded*.

However, turns out that instead of being able to "guide" the "Git Bash" tab to be opened in an existing Windows Terminal window, it creates a new one every single time.

So question:

1. Is there a way to name "sessions" in Windows Terminal (akin to what Tmux allows)?
2. Is it possible to "guide" an invocation of `wt.exe` to make use of this session or create a new one should it already exist?

PS: I am using the stable version of Windows Terminal from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the (at the time of this answer) relatively new `-w` argument to specify a window-name. E.g.:

`wt.exe -w 0 -p "Git Bash" ...`

The current window is always "0", but you can name them whatever you want.  If you want to guarantee a single Windows Terminal window, however, stick to "0".

[Here is the Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows#target-a-specific-window) for more information.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.